# How to gradually fill table data using MySQL, PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL table called "race_data" and it receives live race data constantly. I'm trying to create a live racing scoreboard with data from this table using ajax/php/mysql.

So far, I've managed to organise the data from "race_data" which makes it easier for me to sort the data into Div IDs for my live scoreboard.

I've been piecing together code from other sources and Stack Overflow threads but I'm now at the crossroads where I've run out of ideas how to solve.

Below is part of the 'query.php' file I'm using to check for the last table entry using standard ajax/php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `race_data` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    if ($row['ORDER']) {
    // append order to some divIDs if appears in table row
    $divID = str_replace(" ","_",$row['TYPE']."_".$row['ORDER']);
    } else {
    $divID = str_replace(" ","_",$row['TYPE']);
    }
    $divOutput = $row['VALUE'];
    }

// output the script to replace the innerHTML of the table in the main file
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">function 
    writeDiv() { 
        document.getElementById("'.$divID.'").innerHTML = "'.$divOutput.'"; 
    } 
    </script>
';
```

Below is the 'scoreboard.php' file where the table data needs to be updated from the AJAX responses. How can I use the writeDiv function here to write $divOutput into the right $divID table cells below?

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<!-- force content to bottom (using Bootstrap) -->
<div class="fixed-bottom">
  <!-- start flex box row 1 -->
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="race_position_1"></div>
    <div id="race_position_2"></div>
    <div id="race_position_3"></div>
    <div id="race_position_4"></div>
    <div id="race_position_5"></div>
    <div id="race_margins_1"></div>
    <div id="race_margins_2"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- start flex box row 2 -->
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="race_number"></div>
    <div id="race_name"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- start flex box row 3 -->
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="race_sectional_1"></div>
    <div id="race_sectional_2"></div>
    <div id="race_sectional_3"></div>
    <div id="race_sectional_4"></div>
    <div id="race_run_home"></div>
    <div id="race_wind_speed"></div>
    <div id="race_weather_direction"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- start flex box row 4 -->
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="race_outcome"></div>
    <div id="race_stopwatch"></div>
    <div id="race_time"></div>
    <div id="race_time_official"></div>
  </div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this? All I am seeing is a blank page and no errors to help. Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: what information do the entries in the sql table have? the whole state of the race or only one of the "smaller" divs? In the first case you could just make php `echo` the whole div and then replace the old one with it directly in the ajax request

Comment: This is the problem - the table rows are not full updates of the entire table. I only get up to 4 vars from the query each time. I have already managed to organise the query data to match my div id's (e.g. race_sectional_3 or race_position_2) and give me $divOutput to update the empty div slots. When the race finishes all divs are cleared and I start again when the next race begins... thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:
in query.php file:

```
//output the div element to substitute
echo '<div id="'.$divID.'">'.$divOutput.'</div>'
```

in the scoreboard file:

```
//suppose res is the result of your AJAX query
// that is res=xmlHttp.responseXML
document.getElementById(res.id).innerHTML=res.innerHTML
```

Comment: Thanks :) Trying that solution I get this sample data from query.php:

`<div id='race_sectional_1'>S1: 2.54</div>`

Code in scoreboard.php at the moment is:

``xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
[...]
 document.getElementById(xmlhttp.id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "query.php", true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 loadXMLDoc();
 setInterval(loadXMLDoc, 3000);``

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: use `xmlhttp.responseXML.id` and `xmlhttp.responseXML.innerHTML` instead of `xmlhttp.id` and `xmlhttp.responseText`

Comment: and be sure to to it in the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function

Answer (score 0):

dbac I will try your solution, thanks. In the meantime I made it work using a very longhand approach, but it has helped me follow my own code as I'm new to Javascript/AJAX.

Query.php

```
echo "<div id='".$divID."'>".$divOutput."</div>";
```

Scoreboard.php after line:
 `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {`

```
              var check  = xmlhttp.responseText;
                if (check.indexOf('race_position_1') >= 0 ) {
                  document.getElementById('race_position_1').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_position_2') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_position_2').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_position_3') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_position_3').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_position_4') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_position_4').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_position_5') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_position_5').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_name') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_name').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }  else if (check.indexOf('race_number') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_number').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_sectional_1') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_sectional_1').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                  start();
                  document.getElementById('race_stopwatch').style.border = '1px solid green';
                  document.getElementById('race_stopwatch').style.color = 'green';
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_sectional_2') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_sectional_2').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_sectional_3') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_sectional_3').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                  stop();
                  document.getElementById('race_stopwatch').style.border = '1px solid red';
                  document.getElementById('race_stopwatch').style.color = 'red';
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_sectional_4') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_sectional_4').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_margins_1') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_margins_1').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_margins_2') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_margins_2').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_run_home') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_run_home').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_weather_direction') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_weather_direction').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_weather_wind') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_weather_wind').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_time_official') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_time_official').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else if (check.indexOf('race_time') >= 0) {
                  document.getElementById('race_time').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else {
                  // last option catch all
                }
```

There is a start() and stop() in there as well - adding a Javascript timer from [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/electricg/4372563)

Comment: You know the start() and stop() won't fire unless those events are met in two separate calls?  In an `if` function, once you 'pass the test' (i.e., one of your comparisons is true) that block will be executed and the rest ignored